# Invalid port number while changing current directory through PuTTY in VBScript

Tags: linux, windows, putty

I am using VB Script in QTP to connect to a UNIX server via putty. I need to list all files in the current directory, but am getting an "invalid port number" error when I run the script below:

```vbs
Set p_oWShell= CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
unix_cmd=" cd /home/SHOME/batch"
lscmd = " ls /home/SHOME/batch"
Set oSession = oWShell.exec( puttyLOC & " " & sHost & " -l " & sUser & " -pw " & sPasswd & unix_cmd)
```

*or*

```vbs
Set oSession = oWShell.exec( puttyLOC & " " & sHost & " -l " & sUser & " -pw " & sPasswd & lscmd )
```

Further, I need to upload files from the local Windows machine to Unix server and vice versa.

Note: I tested the below code, and it connects to the server without any issues:

```vbs
Set oSession = oWShell.exec( puttyLOC & " " & sHost & " -l " & sUser & " -pw " & sPasswd)
```

Comment: A couple of suggestions that'd make your question much better (and I realize that English probably isn't your first language). 1, there is a code formatting button at the top of the editor. It looks like `{ }`. Select some code, click it, and it'll be formatted right. 2, please be careful of typos, especially in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putty syntax does not allow you to specify remote command on the same line.

There are two possible options to solve the problem:

1. Use plink.exe insead of putty

`P:\ath\to\plink user@host command`

2. Put your command in a file then use -m switch

`P:\ath\to\putty user@host -m p:\ath\to\file`

For transfering files from a windows box to unix one use pscp.exe utility with similar syntax:

`pscp "P:\ath\to\file.txt"  user@host:/destination/dir/`

plink.exe and pscp.exe are utilities shipped within the putty bundle
I omitted password option in examples.

Comment: Still , am not able to run any commands, even after using plink.the script is like below  {sCommand=sPlinkPath &" -pw "& p_sPasswd &" " & p_sUser&"@"&p_sHost&" cd /home/SHOME/batch"} ...this script giving an error "unexpected end of file". please, can you provide me the script with example which can work

Comment: Try this command in a bare console window first w/o variables and string concatenations:


`P:\ath\to\pink.exe -pw yourpw yourUN@yourHN date`

Just replace yourXX with your values

You should see either date from the remote host or error message.
Once that solved you can continue with VB scripting to see what may be wrong on that level

Just remember the very first connection prompts you to confirm host identitiy manualy, means a human must confirm it by pressing y, afterwards it can be used in scripts.

Comment: Thank you Tagwint, i am able to connect and listing files from a directory.{strCommand11 = pathPLINK  & " -ssh -pw " & " "& rm_pwd &" " & rm_user & "@" & Host & "  "& unix_cmd1 & " >>D:\Test\Logs\log.txt" }. i have one more doubt here is there any possibility to send two commands at a time in one line ....like ex:" cd /home/SHOME/batch" and " ls /home/SHOME/batch"

Comment: Sure you can write it in one row using quotes and  ; delimiter
`P:\ath\to\pink.exe -pw yourpw yourUN@yourHN 'cmd1 ; cmd2; cmd3'`
Mind that ; delimiter wont make stop in case a command fails. Alterantive delimiter is && which gurantees that next command will only executed if previous succeed. You may have some issues with escaping & though as you command is prepared in VB before running. So it's up to you what delimter to chose.

Comment: My scenario is ,connect to the server , change directory to required directory ftom home directory , push csv file from local to unix server directory and get the log files from unix server and move logs to local windows.  Please suggest me which way is better to handle this scenario.am completely new to do these kind of processes.

Comment: For that scenario you dont need execute commands on remote host, since that's trivial file transfer:


1. Upload csv:

`P:\ath\to\pscp.exe P:\ath\to\file.csv -pw yourpw yourUN@yourHN:/remote/path/`

2. Download log

`P:\ath\to\pscp.exe -pw yourpw yourUN@yourHN:/remote/path/to/file.log P:\ath\to\`

Comment: Thank you, i can able to download logs from remote to local now. but while uploading file from local to unix ,getting an error "Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password: " , is there any solution to avoid this?

Comment: Check the command in console window before wrap it into script. You do set password with -pw switch, it should not prompt you for it, unless it is wrong/missed or there's some other syntax error. Please double check the upload command syntax. Provide the full console window output if you still fail with it.

Comment: Thank you,Tagwint...finally i got it worked.{strCommand=pathPSCP & " -pw " & rm_pwd & " -scp " & localPath & " " & rm_user & "@" & rm_host & ":" & remotePath & " >> C:\TestS\Ret\file.txt"}