# backup from server to computer (SSH)

Tags: ssh, backup, command

Could you tell me, how can I backup files from remote server to computer storage disk? I use Windows and program PuTTy to connect to server through ssh. Can you write a command I need to use to back up files f.e. to C:\Backup ?

Comment: Putty comes along with  plink utility which you can use. Check my answer to similar question http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182895/84561 for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a windows environment either use cigwin or even easier with WINSCP (https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) which works via sftp (ssh file transfer protocol).